# Mongoose: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i try to get populate record with null _id, "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model" error display.
My code is:

```
objModel.find().populate('cityId').exec(function (err, res) {});
```

It's work good. But when 'cityId' is null, error display.

How to handle null condition in populate.

Comment: Probably your cityId is "" instead of null.Thats the problem.

Comment: any solution for this issue??